# All factors of big numbers in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, factors

I am trying to find out all factors of numbers which are of the order of 10^18... But there are time constraints which are creating a problem.
What i did was to use Sieve of Eratosthenes to find factors and then store the factors but it is slow.......

Comment: Indeed. That's why public key encryption algorithms work: factoring large numbers (on the order of 10^200) takes too long to be practical.

Comment: @PeteBecker `10^18` is totally brute-forcable by trial division. `10^9` divisions would probably only take a few minutes on a decent computer. But I suppose the the OP never specified what is "too slow".

Comment: @Mysticial - fair enough. I was just making a general point about speeding up factoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If space is not a problem, you could store a list of prime numbers up to 10^9 (lists are available for [download](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/)) and use it to factorize any number up to 10^18.
You could also use factoring algorithms (like pollard's rho, or [others](http://www.frenchfries.net/paul/factoring/source.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend to read Wiki article on this Integer factorization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

General purpose factorization methods are slow. However, may be try to use some special purpose methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the idea of storing a list of primes p<=10^9 to factor numbers N<=10^18 is that for any particular N you would still need to loop over the primes p<=sqrt(N) and check whether or not N%p==0.  This is not the fastest way to do business.

It's not clear from your question if you want to factor a bunch of numbers that are order 10^18, or if you want to factor **all** numbers N<=10^18.  The first case is doable depending on how many N you want to factor and how fast it needs to be.  The second case, factoring **all** numbers N<=10^18, is not doable, because that would entail more than 10^18 operations (at least one for each number to be factored).  Considering that computers can do on the order of 10^9 operations per second, and there are on the order of 10^7 seconds in the year, you'd be factoring for a long time.

If you just want to factor a bunch of numbers N on the order of 10^18, then there are lots of ways to do this. The "best" way depends on the properties of the specific numbers.  For example, random integers around 10^18 are a lot easier to factor on average than integers that are the product of two primes each of order 10^9, because small factors can be eliminated with trial division before moving to a more sophisticated algorithm. This is more a computational number theory question than a programming question.  If this is your question, I recommend to it to the [Factoring section of mersenneforum.org](http://www.mersenneforum.org/forumdisplay.php?f=19).

If you want a quick and dirty solution that is not ridiculously slow then don't reinvent the wheel.  Try for example GMP-ECM or see if PARI/GP can solve your problem.